How to hide Chrome's side panel using a keyboard shortcut in Chrome Extension
I would like to write an extension that shows and hides a side panel when Ctrl+Space is pressed. I came up with the following solution:
background.js
var sidePanelOpen = false;

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
  console.log(`Command: ${command}`);

  if (!sidePanelOpen) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, ([tab]) => {
      chrome.sidePanel.open({ tabId: tab.id });
    });
    sidePanelOpen = true;
  } else {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, ([tab]) => {
      console.log(`Disabling sidepanel: ${tab.id}`);
      chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({ tabId: tab.id, enabled: false });
      console.log(`Disabled sidepanel: ${tab.id}`);
    });
    sidePanelOpen = false;
  }
});

manifest.json
{
  "name": "Test Side Panel",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "sidePanel",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "side_panel": {
    "default_path": "panel.html"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "commands": {
    "toggle-side-panel": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Space",
      },
      "description": "Toggle side panel"
    }
  }
}

The Chrome side panel opens as expected, but it does not hide when Ctrl+Space is pressed a second time. The logs for disabling are printed, but the operation appears to be a no-op.
What am I doing wrong?

Use chrome.runtime.sendMessage('close') and in your panel's listener just call close()

It works great! Thanks a bunch!
